# Element only is found when outputting in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am making the following call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= POST_CALENDAR_GET_EVENT; ?>',
    data: {
        'token': $('meta[name=token]').attr("content"),
        'id': calEvent.id
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    complete: function (data) {
        var $event = $('#myEditEvent');
        console.log($event.find('input[my_name="title"]'));
        $event.find('input[my_name="title"]').val(data.title);
        $event.find('input[my_name="date"]').val(data.date);
        $event.find('input[my_name="start_time"]').val(data.start_time);
        $event.find('input[my_name="end_time"]').val(data.end_time);
        $event.find('input[my_name="street1"]').val(data.street1);
        $event.find('input[my_name="street2"]').val(data.street2);
        $event.find('input[my_name="city"]').val(data.city);
        $event.find('input[my_name="state"]').val(data.state);
        $event.find('input[my_name="zip"]').val(data.zip);

        $("#myEditEvent").modal();
        NProgress.done();
    }
});
```

When I do this, the inputs cannot be found in the DOM. I get the `prevObject` object back from jQuery. I know the elements exists and I have tried to call them in different ways (like using the class selectors).

My confusion is that I *can* find them when I run the *exact* same code on the console... **Why?**

```
<div id="myEditEvent" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editEventModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
      ×
    </button>
    <h5 id="editEventModal">
      Edit Event
    </h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="formField">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
          <span class="fLabel">
            Title                                           
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="title" name="events[title]">
      </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              Date                                          
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="date" disabled="disabled" id="editEventDate" name="events[date]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              Start Time                                            
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="start_time" class="timepicker" name="events[start_time]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              End Time                                          
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="end_time" class="timepicker" name="events[end_time]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              Street *          
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="street1" name="addresses[street1]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              Line 2                                                                
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="street2" name="addresses[street2]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              City *            
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="city" name="addresses[city]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              State *           
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="state" name="addresses[state]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formField">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <span class="fLabel">
              Zip *         
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="span10">

        <input type="text" my_name="zip" name="addresses[zip]">
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="button bSky sButton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
      Close
    </button>
    <button class="button bMuddy sButton" id="updateEvent">
      Update Event
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using this: $('input[my_name="title"]').val() ?

Comment: Are you sure the `complete` callback is getting executed? Are there any errors from the AJAX call?

Comment: @Pavlo: I need it to be inside the #myEditEvent div.

Comment: @Zero21xxx Yea, console.log($event.find('input[my_name="title"]')); Does run and I get the following object back from JQuery: [input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "#myEditEvent input[my_name="title"]", constructor: function, init: function…]

Comment: If that's the case, then the element is found, so what's the problem?

Comment: No it was not, the prevObject that is return means that JQuery did not find any elements.

Comment: @Pavlo It works ONLY in the console... :-/

Comment: So, if you put this line in your code: $('#myEditEvent input[my_name="title"]').val('TEST') it won't work? Please check it again.

Comment: @Pavlo Just tried... didn't work. But when I do it through the console.... it works! GRrrrrr.

Comment: @user3179844: What? No. The `prevObject` contains the elements that have been selected first. So the `prevObject` returned by `$('#foo').find('span')` will contain the elements selected by `$('#foo')`, because `.find('span')` was executed on that selection. `$element.find('input')` isn't executed differently when you pass it to `console.log`, so the problem is something else. I'm pretty sure the elements are selected, but something else is off. Unfortunately you haven't explained what you expect and what happens. You already jumped to conclusions which makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but it only gets returned if no elements where found. It is a pointer to the previous object only. If JQUery finds something it will return the objects it found, but no prevObject.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: **Every** jQuery object has a `prevObject` property, no matter whether elements have been found or not. Here is an exmaple which hopefully convinces you: http://jsfiddle.net/53PAY/ (note how every element exists and there is still a `prevObject` property). `$event.find('input[my_name="title"]')` doesn't return the `prevObject`, it returns a jQuery object with a `prevObject` property.

Comment: @FelixKling when I run the following in the console:
$('#myEditEvent input[my_name="title"]');
I get this:
[<input type=​"text" my_name=​"title" name=​"events[title]​">​]

Which is what I need in my code

Comment: Yes, for some reason, sometimes the console displays the same object differently. Use `console.dir($(...))` in both cases and note that the output is the same. The output `[input, prevObject:…]` means that you have an array like object (jQuery objects are array like), with a propert `0` which is the found `input` element, and a `prevObject` property and other properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47579/discussion-between-user3179844-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it turns out the problem was actually quite obvious:

Instead of using the `complete` callback, you have to use the `success` callback. `conmplete` doesn't get the response passed in as argument, but the `jqXHR` object.

And since `data` doesn't refer to the response, `data.title` and all the other properties will return `undefined`, which makes `.val` actually *get* the value, not *set* it.

---

**To be clear:** The problem had nothing to do with finding or not finding the element.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when DOM elements can't be found by a script but can be found when running the same code from the console it's because the script is executing before the browser has had a chance to render the DOM elements in question. Is your script at the top of your HTML page? If so, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* place or call your code here */ })
```

to ensure the script doesn't fire off until the page has been fully loaded.

Comment: My code is at the bottom of the page after all of my HTML. I have it in an object I created. And that call is only called on a click event...